# oracle procedure called from shell script

Tags: oracle

I have one stored procedure which is working fine when executed as below- I am running Oracle SQL developer

```
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
    declare
    return_val number;
    BEGIN
    pm_own.emav_input_check(TO_DATE('04/19/2014','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('04/20/2014','MM/DD/YYYY'),return_val);
   dbms_output.put_line(return_val);
    END;
```

*stored procedure*-

```
 create or replace
PROCEDURE        emav_input_check(last_bus_day IN DATE, price_date IN DATE, o_param OUT NUMBER)
AS

   bbg_yest       NUMBER;
   bbg_today      NUMBER;
   drates_yest    NUMBER;
   drates_today   NUMBER;
   equity_yest    NUMBER;
   equity_today   NUMBER;
   index_yest     NUMBER;
   index_today    NUMBER;
   retval         INTEGER;
   retval1        INTEGER;
   retval2        INTEGER;
   retval3        INTEGER;
   retval4        INTEGER;
BEGIN

   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO bbg_yest
     FROM Crd_Own.Bbg_Oiv v
     WHERE asof_date = last_bus_day;

   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO bbg_today
     FROM Crd_Own.Bbg_Oiv
     WHERE asof_date = price_date;


   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO drates_yest
       FROM pm_own.deposit_rates
       WHERE     asof_date = last_bus_day
            AND currency_code IN ('USD', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'JPY ')
            AND TERM_WEEKS = 0
            AND MARKET = 'L';

   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO drates_today
       FROM pm_own.deposit_rates
       WHERE     asof_date = price_date
            AND currency_code IN ('USD','EUR', 'GBP', 'JPY ')
            AND TERM_WEEKS = 0
            AND MARKET = 'L';

   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO equity_yest
       FROM pm_own.BDVD_FORECAST_EQUITY
       WHERE asof_date = last_bus_day;

   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO equity_today
       FROM pm_own.BDVD_FORECAST_EQUITY
       WHERE asof_date = price_date;


   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO index_yest
       FROM pm_own.BDVD_FORECAST_INDEX
       WHERE asof_date = last_bus_day;

   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO index_today
       FROM pm_own.BDVD_FORECAST_INDEX
       WHERE asof_date = price_date;

   IF bbg_yest != 0
   THEN
     SELECT ( (bbg_today - bbg_yest) * 100) / bbg_yest INTO retval1
     FROM DUAL;
   ELSE
     retval1 := 0;
   END IF;

   IF drates_yest != 0
   THEN
     SELECT ( (drates_today - drates_yest) * 100) / drates_yest INTO retval2
     FROM DUAL;
   ELSE
     retval2 := 0;
   END IF;

   IF equity_yest != 0
   THEN
     SELECT ( (equity_today - equity_yest) * 100) / equity_yest INTO retval3
     FROM DUAL;
   ELSE
     retval3 := 0;
   END IF;

   IF index_yest != 0
   THEN
     SELECT ( (index_today - index_yest) * 100) / index_yest INTO retval4
     FROM DUAL;
   ELSE
     retval4 := 0;
   END IF;


   retval := 0;

   IF retval1 < 0 AND ABS (retval1) > 20
   THEN
      retval := 1;
   ELSIF retval2 < 0 AND ABS (retval2) > 20
   THEN
      retval := 2;
   ELSIF retval3 < 0 AND ABS (retval3) > 20
   THEN
      retval := 3;
   ELSIF retval4 < 0 AND ABS (retval4) > 20
   THEN
      retval := 4;
   END IF;

   o_param := retval;
END;


    SELECT COUNT (*) INTO bbg_yest
    FROM Crd_Own.Bbg_Oiv v
    WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('last_bus_day', 'mm/dd/yyyy');

    SELECT COUNT (*) INTO bbg_today    
    FROM Crd_Own.Bbg_Oiv
    WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('price_date', 'mm/dd/yyyy');


    SELECT COUNT (*) INTO drates_yest
    FROM pm_own.deposit_rates
    WHERE     asof_date = TO_DATE ('last_bus_day', 'mm/dd/yyyy')         
    AND currency_code IN (' USD', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'JPY ')
    AND TERM_WEEKS = 0;

    SELECT COUNT (*) INTO drates_today
    FROM pm_own.deposit_rates
    WHERE     asof_date = TO_DATE ('price_date', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
    AND currency_code IN (' USD', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'JPY ');

    SELECT COUNT (*) INTO equity_yest
    FROM pm_own.BDVD_FORECAST_EQUITY
    WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('last_bus_day', 'mm/dd/yyyy');

    SELECT COUNT (*) INTO equity_today
    FROM pm_own.BDVD_FORECAST_EQUITY
    WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('price_date', 'mm/dd/yyyy');


    SELECT COUNT (*) INTO index_yest
    FROM pm_own.BDVD_FORECAST_INDEX
    WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('last_bus_day', 'mm/dd/yyyy');

    SELECT COUNT (*) INTO index_today
    FROM pm_own.BDVD_FORECAST_INDEX
    WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('price_date', 'mm/dd/yyyy');

    IF bbg_yest != 0
    THEN
    SELECT ( (bbg_today - bbg_yest) * 100) / bbg_yest INTO retval1
    FROM DUAL;
    ELSE
    retval1 := 0;
    END IF;

    IF drates_yest != 0
    THEN
    SELECT ( (drates_today - drates_yest) * 100) / drates_yest INTO retval2
    FROM DUAL;
    ELSE
    retval2 := 0;
    END IF;

    IF equity_yest != 0
    THEN
    SELECT ( (equity_today - equity_yest) * 100) / equity_yest INTO retval3
    FROM DUAL;
    ELSE
    retval3 := 0;
    END IF;

    IF index_yest != 0
    THEN
    SELECT ( (index_today - index_yest) * 100) / index_yest INTO retval4
    FROM DUAL;
    ELSE
    retval4 := 0;
    END IF;


    retval := 0;

    IF retval1 < 0 AND ABS (retval1) > 20
    THEN
    retval := 1;
    ELSIF retval2 < 0 AND ABS (retval2) > 20
    THEN
    retval := 2;
    ESIF retval3 < 0 AND ABS (retval3) > 20
    THEN
    retval := 3;
    ELSIF retval4 < 0 AND ABS (retval4) > 20
    THEN
    retval := 4;
    END IF;

    o_param := retval;
    END;
```

*but Now when I am trying to call the above procedure from shell script as-*

```
  #!/bin/bash

  price_date="05/20/2014"

  last_bus_day="05/19/2014"

  ORAPWD=`cat /appl/${ENV_BASE}data/data/U/control/.xfile_svc_op`


    model_check=`sqlplus -s` <<....END
    svc_op/${ORAPWD}@${ORACLE_SERVER}
    var return_val number;
    set feedback off
    set heading off
    set pagesize 0
    execute PM_OWN.emav_input_check(TO_DATE($last_bus_day,'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE($price_date,'MM/DD/YYYY'),:return_val);
    print return_val;
....END
echo $model_check

*Please correct me where I am wrong.here ORAPWD and ORACLE_SERVER having valid values.My requirement is get the value returned from stored procedure .please let me know where am i missing.Any help will be highly appreciated.
```

Thanks*

Comment: You *still* didn't provide any information about your specific problem. Do you get an error message? Does the output not match what you're expecting?

Comment: are there any issues with the syntax ?when trying to run the script it doesn't get executes.

Comment: How did you verify that your script doesn't get executed? Have you tried replacing $last_bus_day and $price_date with hard-coded values? Have you tried quoting $last_bus_day and $price_date (it looks like that's missing)?

Comment: You still aren't giving enough details of exactly what is wrong - what behaviour or error or results do you get, and what do you expect? In an earlier answer I moved the closing backtick; I don't think they're valid as you have them, does that part actuall work in your shell? Or do you have to hit return to get control back and see a login error afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any information about the error message / wrong output / whatever you're getting, I can only guess. This (and all subsequent conditions like it) is definitely wrong:

```
WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('last_bus_day', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

This tries to convert the literal string `price_date` into a date. What you *probably* meant is

```
WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE (last_bus_day, 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

(note the absence of `'` around last_bus_day). But this is still wrong, since `last_bus_day` **already is** a date.

Assuming you want to return all rows whose date part (without time information) equals the last bus day, you can use

```
WHERE trunc(asof_date) = trunc(last_bus_day)
```

(`TRUNC` - if used without format specifier - returns the date part of a `DATE` value).

Comment: Modified some part of the question-please re look.